# xcopy File Not Found

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I'm trying to copy a file system.exe to a folder using xcopy in a .bat file. Here is the code. The system.exe file is in same directory as the .bat file.

```
md "C:\Users\Public\sys\"
set copy="%~dp0system.exe"
set target="C:\Users\Public\sys\"
xcopy /c copy target /i /r /f
```

I also tried this.

```
xcopy /c "copy" "target" /i /r /f
```

And this.

```
xcopy /c "%~dp0system.exe" "C:\Users\Public\sys\" /i /r /f
```

All gave the same response

```
File not found
```

The first two tries gives

```
File not found - copy
```

If the above lines succeed, the following lines in the .bat will create a shortcut to the copy of system.exe at the startup folder.

```
set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%programdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\startup.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Users\Public\sys\system.exe" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%
cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
```

That's what I hoped to achieve. Any help appreciated.

add:

I ran the .bat as administrator

Comment: Try this: `xcopy /c /i /r /f "%copy%" "%target%"`; you nee to enclose a variable with `%` sogns to expand (read) it; I recommend not using `copy` as a variable name as there is also such a command...

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use this `%copy%` and `%target%`

EDIT: @aschipfl got it first. Sorry not to look at your comment first.

Comment: I think you should give @aschipfl credit, if you answer with what he said in the comments more than an hour before you

Comment: @DennisvanGils I am so sorry, I was in a hurry and did not even look at the comments. Will edit now. Again Sorry.